# R shiny columns in data table are not filled but no error

Tags: r, shiny

Im building a data table with salaries of men and women which I retrieve from a csv file. The code runs and I get a data table, but the columns for salary and "pensioengrondslag" are missing. 
The way I have coded it below is so I can look up the salary for each gender at the given age.
R does not return an error and I've been through my code many times now, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Maybe someone else knows? Some help would be greatly appreciated! 
This is my code:

server.R:

```
library(prodlim)
library(lubridate)
library(DT)
library(eeptools)


function(input, output) {
  insert <- reactive({

    # Genereer geboortedata
    GeboorteDatum <- sample(seq(as.Date('1900/01/02'), as.Date(input$geboorteData[2]), by = "day"), input$aantalDeelnemers, replace = TRUE)

    # Genereer het geslacht
    if (input$manVrouwVerhouding == "alleen mannen") {
      Geslacht <- sample("M", replace = TRUE, size = input$aantalDeelnemers)
    }
    if (input$manVrouwVerhouding == "0.9/0.1") {
      Geslacht <- sample(c("M","V"), replace = TRUE, size = input$aantalDeelnemers, prob = c(0.9,0.1))
    }
    if (input$manVrouwVerhouding == "0.8/0.2") {
      Geslacht <- sample(c("M","V"), replace = TRUE, size = input$aantalDeelnemers, prob = c(0.8,0.2))
    }
    if (input$manVrouwVerhouding == "0.7/0.3") {
      Geslacht <- sample(c("M","V"), replace = TRUE, size = input$aantalDeelnemers, prob = c(0.7,0.3))
    }
    if (input$manVrouwVerhouding == "0.6/0.4") {
      Geslacht <- sample(c("M","V"), replace = TRUE, size = input$aantalDeelnemers, prob = c(0.6,0.4))
    }
    if (input$manVrouwVerhouding == "0.5/0.5") {
      Geslacht <- sample(c("M","V"), replace = TRUE, size = input$aantalDeelnemers, prob = c(0.5,0.5))
    }
    if (input$manVrouwVerhouding == "0.4/0.6") {
      Geslacht <- sample(c("M","V"), replace = TRUE, size = input$aantalDeelnemers, prob = c(0.4,0.6))
    }
    if (input$manVrouwVerhouding == "0.3/0.7") {
      Geslacht <- sample(c("M","V"), replace = TRUE, size = input$aantalDeelnemers, prob = c(0.3,0.7))
    }
    if (input$manVrouwVerhouding == "0.2/0.8") {
      Geslacht <- sample(c("M","V"), replace = TRUE, size = input$aantalDeelnemers, prob = c(0.2,0.8))
    }
    if (input$manVrouwVerhouding == "0.1/0.9") {
      Geslacht <- sample(c("M","V"), replace = TRUE, size = input$aantalDeelnemers, prob = c(0.1,0.9))
    }
    if (input$manVrouwVerhouding == "alleen vrouwen") {
      Geslacht <- sample("V", replace = TRUE, size = input$aantalDeelnemers)
    }

    # Bereken leeftijden
    vectorDatumBeginDitJaar <- sample(as.Date('2018/01/01'), size = input$aantalDeelnemers, replace = TRUE)
    Leeftijd <- as.integer(age_calc(GeboorteDatum, vectorDatumBeginDitJaar, units = "years"))

    ## Creër salaris

    # Lees bestand in
    salaris <- read.csv("inkomens.csv", header = TRUE)
    leeftijdenBestand <- salaris[, "X...Leeftijd"]

    # Bepaal leeftijden waarop pensioen opgebouwd wordt (0-20 en 67-130 niet)
    pensioenOpbouwLeeftijden <- function(x){
      ouderDanPlft <- match(x, seq(67:130), nomatch = "NA")
      a <- c(0,seq(0:19))
      nieuw <- match(Leeftijd, a, nomatch = 0)
      inverse <- match(nieuw, "0", nomatch = "NA")
      salarisLeeftijden <- ouderDanPlft * inverse
      salarisLeeftijden
    }

    # Zoek voor elke leeftijd de index van de bijbehorende salaris
    teGebruikenLeeftijd <- pensioenOpbouwLeeftijden(Leeftijd)
    zoekIndices <- match(teGebruikenLeeftijd, leeftijdenBestand)

    # Bepaal de salaris per leeftijd voor mannen
    y <- match(Geslacht, "M")
    salarisMannen <- y*zoekIndices

    # Bepaal de salaris per leeftijd voor vrouwen
    x <- match(Geslacht, "V")
    salarisVrouwen <- x*zoekIndices

    # Creër schalen (kolom opzoeken)
    salarisMannenCategorie1 <- salaris[salarisMannen, 2]
    salarisMannenCategorie2 <- salaris[salarisMannen, 3]
    salarisMannenCategorie3 <- salaris[salarisMannen, 4]
    salarisMannenCategorie4 <- salaris[salarisMannen, 5]
    salarisMannenCategorie5 <- salaris[salarisMannen, 6]

    salarisVrouwenCategorie1 <- salaris[salarisVrouwen, 7]
    salarisVrouwenCategorie2 <- salaris[salarisVrouwen, 8]
    salarisVrouwenCategorie3 <- salaris[salarisVrouwen, 9]
    salarisVrouwenCategorie4 <- salaris[salarisVrouwen, 10]
    salarisVrouwenCategorie5 <- salaris[salarisVrouwen, 11]

    # Link input aan salaris schaal
    if(input$salarisSchaal == "schaal 1"){
      Salaris <- salarisMannenCategorie1 + salarisVrouwenCategorie1
    }
    if(input$salarisSchaal == "schaal 2"){
      Salaris <- salarisMannenCategorie2 + salarisVrouwenCategorie2
    }
    if(input$salarisSchaal == "schaal 3"){
      Salaris <- salarisMannenCategorie3 + salarisVrouwenCategorie3
    }
    if(input$salarisSchaal == "schaal 4"){
      Salaris <- salarisMannenCategorie4 + salarisVrouwenCategorie4
    }
    if(input$salarisSchaal == "schaal 5"){
      Salaris <- salarisMannenCategorie5 + salarisVrouwenCategorie5
    }


    # Parttime percentage
    #Parttime_Percentage <- as.numeric(100, input$aantalDeelnemers)

    # Bereken aanspraak
    Pensioengrondslag <- (Salaris - input$franchise)

    # Creër tabel
    data <- data.frame(GeboorteDatum, Leeftijd , Geslacht, Salaris, Pensioengrondslag)
    data
  })

  # render table
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    insert()
  }))
}
```

ui.R:

```
# Add things to app

fluidPage(
  titlePanel("PensioenFonds"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("aantalDeelnemers",
                   "Aantal deelnemers pensioenfonds: ",
                   100, min=0),

      dateRangeInput("geboorteData",
                     "Geboortedata van de deelnemers: ", start = '1900/01/02', end = '2018/01/02', format = "dd/mm/yyyy"),

      selectInput("manVrouwVerhouding",
                  "Verhouding Man/Vrouw: ",
                  choices = c("alleen mannen", "0.9/0.1", "0.8/0.2", "0.7/0.3", "0.6/0.4", "0.5/0.5", "0.4/0.6", "0.3/0.7", "0.2/0.8", "0.1/0.9", "alleen vrouwen")),

      selectInput("salarisSchaal",
                  "Salaris schaal: ",
                  choices = c("schaal 1", "schaal 2", "schaal 3", "schaal 4", "schaal 5")),

      numericInput("franchise",
                   "Franchise: ",
                   13344, min=0)

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the "NA"s in the final vector. Changing the "NA"'s to 0, with the following piece of code, fixed my issue:

```
na.zero <- function (x) {
      x[is.na(x)] <- 0
      return(x)
    }
```